# Ok Google will not launch the application?

Tags: android, google-voice-search

I am working with okgoogle in android and want to launch my android application through okgoogle voice search.

For example:
If i say ok google..
open myApplication

So my application should be launched,but this it not working for my application.

And when i say 
ok google 
open Facebook
Then it redirects me to the facebook app.

Please help!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android App Integrated with OK Google](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30689606/android-app-integrated-with-ok-google)

Comment: But is it support custom commands? like open myApplication