# Android Voice Actions for Messaging

Tags: android, messaging, google-assistant-sdk, google-voice-actions

I'm​ developing a small messaging app on my own and I was wondering if there is a possibility to allow the user to send messages using the Google Assistant. (Like WhatsApp and Google Allo)

Which API could I use to archive this?

Comment: Hey mate are you talking of https://developers.google.com/actions/

Comment: 2 libs/sample apps to look over .... https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/tree/master/examples/android/helloworld/app      https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/speech

Comment: @AyushBansal do I need to create a custom action? To clearify: If the user has the messenger installed, one could send a message by just saying "Ok Google, send a message using *** to ***".

Comment: Am trying , i will let u know if I am able to code it properly .

Comment: @chris go through this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=91&v=PS1FbB5qWEI

Comment: @AyushBansal Okay this helps to get the user a way of searching within an app. Is there a way for message interaction? WhatsApp has this dialogue way with Google now which allows sending messages even without starting WhatsApp.

Comment: yeah just tried that feature it's awesome man . let me try . it will take sme time though (2-3days).

Answer (score 0):

Before going through the code please go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30689606/android-app-integrated-with-ok-google) links answer along with comments .

So as mentioned there are two types of actions that can be registered
1) Custom Action 
2) System Action
 Here app has been registered with `TAKE A NOTE` action(a system generated action).
This is registered in the Manifest to let the system know that it accepts the intents which are related to taking a note.(Hope i have not over explained it)

=== Code ===

Manifest.xml

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.actions.CREATE_NOTE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.VOICE"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class VoiceAction extends AppCompatActivity {

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_voice_action);
         Intent t = getIntent();
         String s = t.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
         System.out.println("====" + s);

     } }
```

This how i tested it

Ok Google -> take a note -> google asks me choose an app -> choose the app to be tested -> give a note or a text to it -> see your log (text you said is printed there).

I will edit the answer to meet your need exactly in some time . Hope this helps

Comment: Thabks for your research but this actions are quite limited and I don't see a way interacting for messaging services like WhatsApp does..

Comment: All available categories are listed here: https://developers.google.com/voice-actions/system/

Comment: You r right but i couldn't get my hands on anything related to messaging.

Comment: Thats exactly my problem I don't get it how WhatsApp could integrate itself this way

Comment: i do have a workaround in mind , let me try it . I will let u know if it works out or if i find something else

Comment: @AyushBansal Did you get any success?

Answer (score 0):

I saw something in the WhatsApp manifest :

Apparently they are using this action : 
com.google.android.voicesearch.SEND_MESSAGE_TO_CONTACTS

No trace of that in any docs...
Coincidence, I think not...

https://github.com/GigaDroid/Decompiled-Whatsapp/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml