# Send message with google now using my app

Tags: android, android-manifest, messaging, google-now

I'm developing a messaging app and I want to send a message using google now.
Like we can do in some steps:

1. says "Ok google, send message" or "ok Google send message with (messaging app name)"
2. choose contact
3. write or says the message
4. and send it.
5. [here a screen shot with hangouts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2A5rb.png)

I seek and find I need to add intent-filter to make its work.
I succeed to make an app that uses Google Now to set a clock or to take a note.

But I still stuck on **what intents I need to put in the manifest to send message using Google Now.**

I have the same question that this post :
[Sending messages from Google Now](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42247015/8440308) but he don't have any answer.

I check that: [Android App Integrated with OK Google](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30689606/8440308) and a lot of other posts but that not give me the answer.