# Make an android phone respond to custom sound (custom hotword)

Tags: android, accessibility

I am with my daughter in the hospital and she is asleep. I would like to leave the room for a few minutes but don't want to upset her if she wakes up (she can't see or move much)

The first thing I though about is leaving the phone in the room and have it play a message if she speaks. I thought about the 'OK Google' type hotwords but I don't think they are customizable.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Voice Actions API](https://developers.google.com/voice-actions/system/) should have what it is you're looking for. There's another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30689606/android-app-integrated-with-ok-google) which will lead you in the right direction. [Custom Voice Actions](https://developers.google.com/voice-actions/custom-actions) from my understanding allow developers to implement their own commands.

However if all you want to do is detect voices and then perform an action, i would go down the route of just detecting a voice. A [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955041/voice-detection-in-android-application/7976877#7976877) should have the information you need.